# Singletons in Multiple Classloader and VM cases

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton, classloader

How to safely code Singletons in case of two or more Classloaders and VMs. I see this problem explained at: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/singletons/

Solutions ?

Comment: What problem are you referring to in particular? A singleton per group of classloaders or a singleton per JVM or a singleton per cluster of JVMs?

Comment: Multiple VM's mean you need inter-vm communication.  There be dragons!

Comment: Best solution: Avoid [mutable] singletons. Always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want share a singleton between ClassLoaders, you have a common parent load the singleton, or you can have each ClassLoader explicitly define which classes Singleton you want that Classloader to use.

Comment: hmmm. not sure if this will help, but here is an example loading and unloading classloaders. http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/07/java-secret-loading-and-unloading.html To share a singleton, you need to make the class accessible to the parent Classloader, so it loads it.  You can override the loadClass method to if want to be selective on a per class loader basis.

Answer (score 2):

The article clearly states that distributed applications should stay away from Singletons. Any particular problem you are trying to solve here? Also, for singletons which hold true constants which are never modified during the application run, multiple "instances" of your "singleton" shouldn't pose a problem. In other cases, you are better off injecting your configuration (the dependency injection way of doing things) in the classes which need it.

Comment: Yes, I agree with what you say. I am not trying to solve a specific problem but this was rather a theoretical question

Answer (score 1):

Attention: if the computer has multiple interfaces (IPs) then the same socket (8765) can be bound to all of them (so it is not that foolproof). File is better although there are cases when they can be hidden too (mount over, for example)

Answer (score 0):

1) network socket survives multiple VMs

```
    Port busy 8765 java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

2) so does file

```
    WARNING: Creating a new instance of CacheManager using the diskStorePath
```

safely code Singletons in case of two or more Classloaders and VMs based on these resources (if you really badly need to stick with this anti-pattern)